# Perl in eclipse: ant build

Tags: eclipse, perl, ant, build

When I opened a Perl code in Eclipse and tried to run, it wanted to prompt me which Build to run, for example, run as Ant Build.

So what should I do in order to make the code running? I used to run those Perl codes in Eclipse directly, without incurring these additional prompts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `EPIC` Plug-in in Eclispe thereafter you can able to run the Perl code.

see [How to run Perl scripts inside Eclipse?](http://www.epic-ide.org/faq.php#runscript) for more detail.